# Are there any known bugs/issues with MCrypt Library in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, centos, mcrypt

I am wondering are there any issues with the MCrypt library in PHP, because I am making an encryption/decryption test. In the same file I have a encryption and decryption, no functions no nothing. When I encrypt, everything is perfect, but when I start decrypting right after that, the output becomes garbage. I am sure that I am passing the same key and IV, I have even changed the algorithm (3DES and RIJNDEAL-128) in OFB and ECB. Everything is the same.

The versions of MCrypt of my concern are:

> Version 2.5.8
>   API 20021217
>   PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1
>   Apache 2.2.22
>   OS: Ubuntu 12.10 x64
>
> Version: 2.5.8
>   API: 20021217
>   PHP Version 5.3.15
>   Apache 2.2.22
>   OS: CentOS x64 (HostGator Shared)
>
> > Also the problem is not in the x64, because I have previously used ubuntu 12.04 on x86 Machine

**Edit**

```
$time = microtime();
$key_size = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128);
$key = substr(md5($time),0,$key_size);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = substr(sha1($time),0,$iv_size);
$secret = "14 SPROWSTON ROAD";
$crypt =  mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $secret, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
print $crypt;
print "<br />";
echo mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

**Output**

> 14�'�V�>�CN ROAD

Comment: Can you clarify your output? You have two lines for different output but we only see one of those lines.

Comment: Strange... your code works just fine for me (although it warns about a missing parameter to `mcrypt_get_key_size()` and about the use of an empty IV, since you forgot to actually pass `$iv` to `mcrypt_encrypt()` and `mcrypt_decrypt()`).

Comment: @AngrySpartan what two lines do you mean ? Yeah I saw and understand what do you mean.

Comment: He means that your code is printing both the encrypted string and the decrypted output, separated by `<br />`, but you're only showing us one line of output. Please post a [short, self-contained correct example program](http://sscce.org/), and its _exact_ output, demonstrating the problem. (Your current code is fine on the first two accounts -- it's short and self-contained -- but it doesn't demonstrate the problem when _I_ run it, and I fail to see how it could possibly produce the output you're claiming it does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was at the side behind the computer.. It was my own coding error.